# Border hovering over a div (CSS)

Tags: css, html, border

first of all I wanted to give you a fiddle instead but as I ran it, it looked correctly so obviously the problem lies somewhere else in my code and I have no idea where.

Basically, I want rounded borders around the 2 div columns above the footer, however they hover over the divs. Additionally as you can see, the rounded border is hidden behind the div background in the bottom corners. How can I fix these?

Link (sorry for the dodgy-looking link but that's the first free hosting website I could find to test the website before I actually get some proper hosting): http://pawel.net63.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the background image on `#featured-product` not `#bottom-main`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it now looks almost the way I want it to but the top border is still about 20 or so pixels above the heading background (.bottom-heading). I would like it to lie right on top of it.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to explain it more clearly. I want the top part of the border to appear as on this example: http://imgur.com/r68w2 (the red line being where I want the top part of the border to be). It might be a bit hard to see as the background behind the "Featured Project" and "Testimonials" headings is only a little less dark than the rest of the background but basically, now the border and the #featured-project and #testimonials background extend too far to the top. I want to fix that.

Comment: Remove the padding on `#featured-project h3`?

Comment: Ok got it. I had to remove the top margin on h3.